# Scoring deviation from elements

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I'm thinking about how to score deviation from elements.

I have a target elements: $[10,4,8,20]$, and candidate elements: $[9,3,9,21]$ and $[10,4,8,16]$.

Calculate deviation between the target and candidates $[-1,-1,1,1]$ and $[0,0,0,4]$ results in the sum of absolute of difference $[4]$, $[4]$ so, they are same as $[4]$.

I wonder that which one is better? 
And is there a statistical scoring method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming the targets and candidates are matched for position, then your taking the sum of the absolute difference is one possible approach.  Taking the sum of the squares of the differences is another possibility, giving $4$ and $16$, and there can be others.  It depends on your loss function

Comment: @Henry oh thank you!